# Excel Spreadsheet generated by EPPlus

Tags: c#, epplus

Right this is starting to drive me mad, I have a asp:gridview with check boxes, the user has the ability to check which information he/she wants to export to excel, when they click the button the below code is executed, now you can see im doing a for each row in the gridview etc

if the check box for a row is checked i go to the DB execute some information return a datatable and then try and add its values to the Epplus excel spreadsheet, but in the `foreach(datacolum)` and `foreach(DataRow)` it doesnt allow me to use

```
ws.Cells[1, iColumnCount] = c.ColumnName; as it says its read only?
```

but this one excel spread sheet could have 1 - 10 different bits of information depending on how many checkboxes are checked....can someone please help me and put me out of my misery........ :(

heres my full code

```
protected void BtnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool ReportGenerated = false;

    FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo("C:\\Users\\Scott.Atkinson\\Desktop\\book1.xls");
    ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile);
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvPerformanceResult.Rows)
    {
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        CheckBox chkExcel = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkExportToExcel");
        if (chkExcel.Checked)
        {

            HyperLink HypCreatedBy = (HyperLink)row.FindControl("HyperCreatedBy"); //Find the name of Sales agent

            string CreatedBy = HypCreatedBy.Text;
            string Fname = HypCreatedBy.Text;
            string[] names = Fname.Split();
            CreatedBy = names[0];
            CreatedBy = CreatedBy + "." + names[1];

            WebUser objUser = new WebUser(CreatedBy, true);

            DataTable DT = new DataTable();
            LeadOpportunities objLeadOpportunities = new LeadOpportunities();
            DT = objLeadOpportunities.LoadPRCDetail("PRC", objUser.ShortAbbr, objUser.CanViewAllLead, ReportCriteria); // Load the information to export to Excel.

            if (DT.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                ReportGenerated = true;
                //Add the Content sheet
                var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Content");
                ws.View.ShowGridLines = true;

                int iRowCount = ws.Dimension.Start.Row; //Counts how many rows have been used in the Excel Spreadsheet
                int iColumnCount = ws.Dimension.Start.Column; //Counts how many Columns have been used.

                if (iRowCount > 1)
                    iRowCount = iRowCount + 2;
                else
                    iRowCount = 1;

                iColumnCount = 0;

                foreach (DataColumn c in DT.Columns)
                {
                    iColumnCount++;
                    if (iRowCount == 0)
                        ws.Cells[1, iColumnCount] = c.ColumnName;
                    else
                        ws.Cells[iRowCount, iColumnCount] = c.ColumnName;
                }

                foreach (DataRow r in DT.Rows)
                {
                    iRowCount++;
                    iColumnCount = 0;
                    foreach (DataColumn c in DT.Columns)
                    {
                        iColumnCount++;
                        if (iRowCount == 1)
                            ws.Cells[iRowCount + 1, iColumnCount] = r[c.ColumnName].ToString();
                        else
                            ws.Cells[iRowCount, iColumnCount] = r[c.ColumnName].ToString();

                        WorkSheet.Columns.AutoFit(); //Correct the width of the columns
                    }
                }

                pck.Save();
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Users\\Scott.Atkinson\\Desktop\\book1.xls");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Ok iv got it working but it now falls over on the                         int iRowCount = ws.Dimension.Start.Row; //Counts how many rows have been used in the Excel Spreadsheet
                        int iColumnCount = ws.Dimension.Start.Column; //Counts how many Columns have been used. can someone help me get the row/column count?

Comment: what kind of exception it throws?

Answer (score 0):

> it doesnt allow me to use
>   `ws.Cells[1, iColumnCount] = c.ColumnName;`

That line should have been:

```
ws.Cells[1,iColumnCount].Value = c.ColumnName
```

> but it now falls over on the int iRowCount = ws.Dimension.Start.Row; //Counts how many rows have been used in the Excel Spreadsheet int iColumnCount = ws.Dimension.Start.Column; //Counts how many Columns have been used. can someone help me get the row/column count?

The `.Dimension` property gives the address for the range covering the top left cell to the bottom right cell so to get the row count we can use:

```
var rowCount = ws.Dimension.End.Row - ws.Dimension.Start.Row + 1;
```

and similarly for the column count:

```
var colCount = ws.Dimension.End.Column - ws.Dimension.Start.Column + 1;
```